# how to split several strings that contain text separated by commas into array so it contains unique items

Tags: javascript

I have several strings, some contain just a phrase, and others contain phrases separated by commas. How can I split each of the strings and then save them into an array?

Example strings:

```
a = "Shipping, Receiving"
b = "Research and development, Building services"
c = "Cafeteria"
d = "Receiving, Building services, Cafeteria"
```

I need the array to contain:

```
Shipping
Receiving
Research and development
Building services
Cafeteria
```

I'm pulling the data from a web page that is stored in divs with the class "audience".

```
const audience = document.querySelectorAll('.audience'); 
const allcats = [];
audience.forEach((element) => {
      allcats.push(element.textContent.trim());
});
```

I need to know how to step through these and add them to the array.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: Neither your example or desired output aren't JS, so: please update those to show what your input _really_ is, show what real output you want, and show the code you've already written to try to achieve this. Also note that your question is an almost literally answer to itself: how can you split each of the strings and then save them into an array? By splitting each string, and then adding the result of each string split to some array.

Comment: for each string, split the string by comma. Then insert each item into a set, giving you only the unique items in the set

Comment: I guess this is the step that i'm unsure of... I know how to split a string by a character, and I can find examples of splitting a string and making it into an array, but how do I 1. split a string and ADD it to an existing array and 2. remove duplicate entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer loops through your audience divs and splits the content then loops through that content and checks to see if its in the array. If its not in the array, then it is pushed to the array.

```js
const audience = document.querySelectorAll('.audience'); 
const allcats = [];
audience.forEach((element) => {
    element.textContent.split(",").forEach(function(str){
      if(allcats.includes(str.trim()) === false){
         allcats.push(str.trim());
       }
    });
});

console.log(allcats)
```

```html
<div class="audience">Shipping, Receiving</div>
<div class="audience">Research and development, Building services</div>
<div class="audience">Cafeteria</div>
<div class="audience">Receiving, Building services, Cafeteria</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const a = 'Shipping, Receiving';
const b = 'Research and development, Building services';
const c = 'Cafeteria';
const d = 'Receiving, Building services, Cafeteria';
 
// Combine the strings into an array. For
// each split the string using a regex that
// looks for a comma followed by an optional space
// and flatten the remaining nested array with
// `flatMap`
const arr = [a, b, c, d].flatMap(str => {
  return str.split(/,\s?/);
});

// Create a new Set from the array to dedupe the
// elements, and then convert it back into an array
// for viewing
// create an array from the  
console.log([...new Set(arr)]);
```

Additional information

- [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)
- [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Answer (score 0):

Use the split() method, for example:

```js
const str = 'Hear about the new restaurant called Karma, There’s no menu: You get what you deserve';
//  explode by every char
str.split('') // ['H', 'e', 'a', 'r', ' ', 'a', 'b', 'o', 'u', 't', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'n', 'e', 'w', ' ', 'r', 'e', 's', 't', 'a', 'u', 'r', 'a', 'n', 't', ' ', 'c', 'a', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'd', ' ', 'K', 'a', 'r', 'm', 'a', ',', ' ', 'T', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'e', '’', 's', ' ', 'n', 'o', ' ', 'm', 'e', 'n', 'u', ':', ' ', 'Y', 'o', 'u', ' ', 'g', 'e', 't', ' ', 'w', 'h', 'a', 't', ' ', 'y', 'o', 'u', ' ', 'd', 'e', 's', 'e', 'r', 'v', 'e']
// explode by space
str.split(' ') // ['Hear', 'about', 'the', 'new', 'restaurant', 'called', 'Karma,', 'There’s', 'no', 'menu:', 'You', 'get', 'what', 'you', 'deserve']
// explode by comma
str.split(',') // ['Hear about the new restaurant called Karma', ' There’s no menu: You get what you deserve']
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const a = "Shipping, Receiving"
const b = "Research and development, Building services"
const c = "Cafeteria"
const d = "Receiving, Building services, Cafeteria"

const arr = Array.from(new Set(
[
...a.split(',').map(el => el.trim()),
...b.split(',').map(el => el.trim()),
...c.split(',').map(el => el.trim()),
...d.split(',').map(el => el.trim()),
]
))

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your example here's what you could do to get the unique set of words separated by a comma

```js
const a = "Shipping, Receiving"
const b = "Research and development, Building services"
const c = "Cafeteria"
const d = "Receiving, Building services, Cafeteria"

// array of arrays
const preprocess = [a, b, c, d].map(item => item.split(',').map(i => i.trim()))
console.log({preprocess})

// flatten array -> contains duplicates  
const processed = preprocess.reduce((prev, curr) => ([...prev, ...curr]))
// In ES2019 could use [].flat(preprocess)

console.log({processed})

const unique = new Set(processed)

console.log({result: [...unique]})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
let uniquePhrases = [];

let concatStr = a + ',' + b + ',' + c + ',' + d
let split = concatStr.split(',')

split.map( el => {
  let trimmed = (el.trim())
  if(!uniquePhrases.includes(trimmed)) {
    uniquePhrases.push(trimmed)
  } else { return }
})
```

In summation:

- Creates the array you will store values:`uniquePhrases`
- Concatenates strings
- Splits string into array
- Maps array removing any spaces at beginning of each string
- Checks if that phrase exists in uniquePhrases array and pushes to array if it doesn't